# Blender Rig with only one finger

Tags: mesh, armature, bones

this topic has already been discussed but unfortunately the answers doesnt solve my problem. One of the recommandations is to spread the fingers a little bit more before uploading the body mash to mixamo so that the generated hand has 5 instead of only one finger. To do that is is reccomended to spread the fingers a bit more with the aramature, then delete the armature but keep the pose of the fingers / mesh. This doesnt work in my case because when I try to apply the modifier (this is necessary to keep the pose when deleting the aramture) blender says Modifier is disabled, skipping apply. But maybe its a completely other issue why I get only one finger in mixamo. I attached my body fbx file. If anybody is able to load this fbx into mixamo and help me to generarte an armature with 5 fingers this wood be so great! Alex

https://c.gmx.net/@334347682451561386/tosUPd1ASGq0qsK-UNWCFw

Comment: Already found out, that the wrists need to be configured seperatly in mixamo because the robotic right hand of the character differs from the human left hand. I still dont know how to freeze the body mesh when deleting the armature but thats not relevant anymore for the finger issue.

Comment: I had to remove the shade keys to apply the modifier so I could freeze the fingers. When I delete the armature the body mesh (finger position) doesnt change. Thats what I wanted. Now Mixamo kann better recognize each finger to build the right armature.